# How to go fully static in Nuxt.js including download links, images, background images?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I can not figure out how to make nuxt generate fully static website. It makes api call static and that is awesome. But all images, and download links still making request to a remote server.

Is it possible to generate fully static website where all links to external files(`<img src="remote.jpg">`, `<a href="remote.pdf"`, `background-image: url('remote.jpg')`) will be downloaded and placed in local folder and then every url will be replaced to local files? Or nuxt does SSG only for APIs?

Answer (score 0):

You could totally optimize and put all of your assets into the `/static` directory indeed.

It will require some CI or any kind of build step to have them properly updated, organized etc but nothing impossible (this will keep everything in the same place). Meanwhile, having resources outside of your server is not bad in the principle itself neither.